# bidding system in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i'm trying tocreate a biding system with this structure :
users can reserve an auction and then when the auction is starting users can click on a button and this button will rais up the base price. the problem is :

i want to show the last order for all users and this will happen every one seccond and this will be in an update panel that it includes me datalist (showing runnig auctions) and every one seccond this updatepanel should be update and datasource should get data that is very slow.

any suggestion ?

Comment: Suggestion: Use a performance profiler to measure the bottlenecks. I recommend using [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

Comment: might be a dumb question to ask but , Are you using AJAX calls ?

Comment: no i dont use ajax calls because its not my problem, the problem is for every one seccond request to db its not good, i was thinking about caching or something like this

Comment: Why cache anything if you can simply `push` data to "subscribers"? See my point? You're making your own life harder for nothing, read my answer below.

Comment: Yeah i'm searching about pushing data, i have never seen about pushing and comet, i'm searching about how to use comet for pushing data to subscribers browser without refreshing the page. do you know any example or learning about how to use ?

Comment: It all depends on the implementation you finally use. Each offers different things. Look for examples specific to that implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Basically you'll get an event of a bid, then you need to publish it. See [Publish–subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).

Also google for `pub sub asp.net`.

Edit #1: Google for `http push` as well.

Comment: i searched it but nothing :( i dont have any tutorial or basic learns about this please help me :( i want to use it in ASP.NET webapplication